# Post more than one parameter to ajax

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

PHP code :

```
<?php include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $year = $_POST['year'];
 $term= $_POST['term'];
 $semester= $_POST['semester'];
 $class= $_POST['class'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM hostelfee WHERE RegNo = '$name' AND PayYear='$year' AND PayTerm='$term' AND PaySemester='$semester' AND PayClass='$class' ";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo json_encode($row); 
 } 
?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ch() {
      $(document).on('change',function() {
         name = $('#name option:selected').val();
         year = $('#year').val();
          term = $('#term').val();
          semester = $('#semester').val();
          class = $('#class').val();
         $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {name : name,year : year,term:term,semester:semester,class:class},
          url:'getBalance.php',
          success:function (result) {
           $('#Year').val(result['PayYear']);
           $('#student-balance').val(result['Balance']);
          }
         });
        });
     }
        
    </script>
```

I have a payment page where I first have to select student No, Year and term, then the balance of that period will be selected.

The challenge is that I can only send one parameter from PHP to ajax. How to use more than one parameter?

Comment: show us your `ajax` code

Comment: You are currently sending 2 parameters using AJAX to PHP, `name` and `year`.

Comment: I have attached it. and my php code is here,   <?php
include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
//$year = $_POST['year'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM hostelfee WHERE RegNo = '$name' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo json_encode($row);
}
?>

Comment: first thing you are already sending two parameters from ajax and using only one parameter in php code, your question is still not clear, can you explain it more what do you want from here?

Comment: sorry! I posted when i had not included all the parameters because it only works well when its one paramater. but they are actually five parameter, name, year,term,semester and class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function ch() {
                $(document).on('change',function() {
                //use serialize to get multiple value of form. Add your form id - #form. you can also use form name, class
                form_data = $('#form').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {action : 'hostelfee',formdata : form_data},
                    url:'getBalance.php',
                    success:function (result) {
                        $('#category').val(result['PayYear']);
                        $('#student-contact').val(result['Balance']);
                    }
                });
            });
            }

        </script>
```

In getBalance.php file use [parse_str](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the serialize data in array.

```
   if($_POST['action'] == 'hostelfee'){
parse_str($_POST['formdata'], $form_data);

//here will get all the parameter like name, year,term,semester and class etc in array.
print_r($form_data);

//add your code here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your kind help. but now I have this challenge where after selecting correct existing records it works and when select records that do not exist it does not clear the textboxes. is there any way I can clear textboxes when there is no data found? Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you are getting the result add the value else make it null like. success:function (result) {
                    if(result){
                        $('#category').val(result['PayYear']);
                        $('#student-contact').val(result['Balance']);
     }else{
      $('#category').val('');
                        $('#student-contact').val('');
     }
                    }

Comment: It's Not working @Shivendra Singh. I don't know where the problem is exactly